# Next js + Firebase wouldn't work on Netlify

Tags: next.js, netlify

I'm trying to run Next js on top of Netlify, but I get 404s except for the root page, and Netlify doesn't show any logs, so I don't know what the error is.

In the React app, I had to create a `redirects` file under puiblic, so I tried that too, but it doesn't work. What should I do?

Comment: Did  the answers solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a `_redirects` file not `redirects`,You can also use `netlify.toml` instead, and it should be located in [publish directory](https://docs.netlify.com/configure-builds/get-started/#basic-build-settings) it's important!
Here you have few resource which are very helpful ;-) [source-1](https://docs.netlify.com/configure-builds/common-configurations/next-js/) , [source-2](https://docs.netlify.com/routing/redirects/) , [source-3](https://docs.netlify.com/routing/redirects/redirect-options/). Good Luck!

Comment: @k10a You're welocm ;-) Best regards !